# Wrong results while using "find" in terminal

Tags: find

What am I doing wrong and why I need to use "/" to get correct results?
And if I need "/" what is the purpose of it and how do I input it using terminal?
Going thru "media" was just an accident and I have no clue what I did.

```
> jim@jim-desktop:~$ sudo find . -name "dbus*.pc"
[sudo] password for jim:
```

**nothing found**

```
jim@jim-desktop:~$ cd /media
jim@jim-desktop:/media$ cd ..
jim@jim-desktop:/$ sudo find . -name "dbus*.pc"
find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
./usr/lib/pkgconfig/dbus-sharp-glib-2.0.pc
./usr/lib/pkgconfig/dbus-sharp-2.0.pc
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/dbus-1.pc
jim@jim-desktop:/$
```

Comment: When you edit, there are tips on formatting to the right of the text box. You can follow the link to learn more, or just use the toolbar.

Comment: When you did `cd /media` then `cd ..`, you are now in `/` and ran the `find` command in system root `/` directory. if you do `cd  -` you will back to previous path you switched from with `cd  /media`

Answer (score 3):

the "dot" you put after the find command means you will find in the current working directory and sub folders. The `~` in your prompt suggests it is your home directory. You can run the `pwd` command to tell what is your current working directory.

If you want to look for files in "/media", then use

```
sudo find /media -name "dbus*.pc"
```

if you launch

```
sudo find / -name "dbus*.pc"
```

This will look for your files in the whole system and sub-directories "/" means the root of your system.

Comment: find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;

       Runs `file' on every file in or below the current directory. This is a copy from  find man and it does not  totally agree with what have been posted so far.  "in and bellow current directory"   is referenced both for "." and "/" symbols.